# ##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Scripts/Deploy/Deploy-PolicyPlan.ps1'

Tags: azure-devops

Trying to run pipeline with several tasks opening seperated files in the same location, however for this specific task it cannot find the file yet even though it exists.

[image: Folder Structure]

[image: Pipeline code of previous task that runs and for this one it doesn't:]

[image: Error message]

Comment: Notice the leading `/` on that file path in the ENOENT error. Looks like it's being treated as an *absolute* path rather than a relative one. Also this isn't really about programming, maybe a better fit for [devops SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: It is weird that both the scripts `Build-DeploymentPlans.ps1` and `Deploy-PolicyPlan.ps1` are from the same path `Scripts/Deploy/`, while the `Build-DeploymentPlans.ps1` is executed and the script `Deploy-PolicyPlan.ps1` is not found. Would you try and add a step `-script: tree` above the `Deploy Policies` step to show if the scripts are there? By the way, is there any chance the script is not pushed to the `main` branch, which the `single-tenant-pipeline` is defined from? Are you using a `deployment` job and may I know whether the pipeline is running on a Microsoft-hosted agent?

Comment: @AlvinZhao that is for me weird as well... I've added '-script: tree' above Deploy Policies and the output is shown here https://imgur.com/a/vde56vF. I've tried to run it in the main branch, but I get this error while it shows correct https://imgur.com/a/qawMKkn . If I run this pipeline via a branch, then I get the error that it cannot find the file in the existing location.

Edit: Yes I use a deployment job and yes I am using a Microsoft-hosted agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the latest screenshots that shared, the issue could be reproduced when the `ScriptPath` begun with `/`, which would have the task search script under the agent root directory rather than the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` of the `deployment` job. Please check your pipeline defined by the file `Pipelines/single-tenant-pipeline.yml` in the `policies` branch of the repository **epac-policy-as-a-code** and pay attention to the differences in the `ScriptPath` in line `40` and `59`.

[image]

Therefore, please test and remove the first `/` in `ScritpPath` section in line `59` of this yaml pipeline.

By the way, you seemed to have shared a **different** YAML definition in the original post; that pipeline was defined by `single-tenant-pipeline.yml` in the `Pipelines` folder from the `main` branch of another repository **mg-sandbox-repos**.

Hope the findings could help and good luck.

Comment: That solved the issue thank you very much. I feel bad for not seeing this (regarding the '/' ). I removed it and then it worked.